# How to merge two arrays like this example in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

There are two arrays, the first one has three elements, the second one has twelve, as follow:

```
array_foo = ['a','b','c'];
array_bar = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];
```

I want to merge them, and put `a` behind `4`, put `b` behind `8`,put `c` behind `12`,that is：

```
array_result=['1','2','3','4','a','5','6','7','8','b','9','10','11','12','c'];
```

How to do it with Javascript?

**update:**

I am not sure below is good, any better answer?

```
array_bar.forEach((item, index) => {
    let array_foo_first = array_foo.slice(0, 4 * (index + 1) + index);
    let array_foo_last = array_foo.slice(4 * (index + 1) + index);
    array_foo = [
        ...array_foo_first,
        item,
        ...array_foo_last
    ]
});
```

Comment: so the rule is every 4 ``array_bar`` 1 of `array_foo`?

Comment: can you show what you tried and didn't work for you.

Comment: seems like a simple loop, did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 1):

I turns out to be rather simple, you just need to extend a `for` loop a bit:

```js
array_foo=['a','b','c'];
array_bar=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];


for (let i = 4,j=0; i<array_bar.length; i+=4,j++) {
  array_bar.splice(i+j, 0, array_foo[j]);
}

array_bar = array_bar.join();

console.log(array_bar);
```

Quick explanation of the loop:

Instead of just having one index, you are keeping track of two, `i` for `array_bar` and `j` for `array_foo`. You increment `i` by 4 every time, and `i` by one, since you want them spaced out like this (4:1).

```
for (let i = 4,j=0; i<array_bar.length; i+=4,j++)
```

`splice` let's you insert an element at a given position, here we insert the element at `i+j` which is `4+0`, `8+1` and `12+2`, aka always 4 elements from `array_bar` apart

```
array_bar.splice(i+j, 0, array_foo[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is stated by 4 array_bar 1 of array_foo.
Then I would do a small loop that will accomplish that.

This loops based on `array_bar`

Hope this helps :>

```js
var array_foo=['a','b','c'];
var array_bar=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];
var array_new = [];

array_bar.forEach((el,i)=>{
  if((i)%4==0 && i!=0)
    array_new.push(array_foo[(i/4)-1])
  array_new.push(el);
})
array_new.push(array_foo[array_foo.length-1]);

console.log(array_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You could loop through the `foo` array and for each element concatenate a 4 element chunk of `bar` with the current element of `foo` then concatenate the result to `res` containing all previous chunks.

```js
foo = ['a','b','c'];
bar = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];

res = [];
foo.forEach((e,i) => { res = res.concat(bar.slice(4*i,4*i+4)).concat(e) } );

console.log(res)
```

---

### Using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

We can achieve the same result by using `.map` instead:

```
[].concat.apply([], foo.map((e,i) => bar.slice(4*i,4*i+4).concat(e)))
```

So here I'm mapping `foo` as follows:

```
foo[i] <- [bar[4*i], bar[4*i+1], bar[4*i+2], bar[4*i+3], foo[i]] (pseudocode!)
```

Then I concatenate all the arrays into one: with `[].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays)`

```js
foo = ['a','b','c'];
bar = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];

res = [].concat.apply([], foo.map((e,i) => bar.slice(4*i,4*i+4).concat(e)));

console.log(res)
```

---

### Without using [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

The `.concat` method (used in the two previous version) creates a new array. If you're looking for another solution still using `.map`, here it is:

```
foo.map((e,i) => res.push(...bar.slice(i*4, i*4+4), foo[i]));
```

Instead of concatenating arrays, we are pushing a chunk of `bar`'s elements with an element of `foo` for every element of `foo`. I'm also using the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax to unwrap the chunk into arguments passed to `.push`.

```js
foo = ['a','b','c'];
bar = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];

res = [];
foo.map((e,i) => res.push(...bar.slice(i*4, i*4+4), foo[i]));

console.log(res)
```